# In Sublime Text 2 - reopen build output

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublimt Text 2, when I use the build system (make) to run tests, the output is displayed in the build output pane.

However, if I press escape to close the output pane (e.g. to make a fix), I can't find a way to redisplay the output pane to see what else was borked. Have tried to create a custom keybinding to execute show_panel "output", but can't get it working.

Meep?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As you can see in `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` the command for "Show build results" is this:

```
{
  "command": "show_panel", 
  "args": {
    "panel": "output.exec"
  },
  "caption": "Show Build Results",
  "mnemonic": "S"
},
```

so a custom key binding could be this:

```
{ 
  "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+r"],
  "command": "show_panel", 
  "args": {
    "panel": "output.exec"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wish there was a way to toggle this particular panel too. I've tried

    `"command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec", "toggle": true}`

and 

    `"command": "toggle_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec"}`

Neither work

Comment: where do you add this `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+r"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec"} }` code ?

Comment: Preferences > Key Bindings - User

Comment: I had to restart Sublime after adding these key bindings for them to work.

Comment: In sublime text 3 (linux) your packages other than User may be at /opt/sublime_text/Packages.
You can unzip the file Main.sublime-menu from Default to have a look at it:

 `$ unzip -q '/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package' Main.sublime-menu  -d ~/Documents`

-d is an optional directory to unzip to.

Comment: To toggle you push 'escape'. That is 'ctrl+alt+super+r' show it, and 'escape' hide it. Ref from system keybindings: `{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"cancel": true}, "context":[{ "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }]}`

Answer (score 44):

The menu shortcut is under `Tools -> Build Results -> Show Build Results`.

I wish this was under the `View` menu like all the rest of view options...

Comment: On osx, the key binding is <opt><cmd>B

Answer (score 4):

And the key binding to hide the panel:

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+2"], 
  "command": "hide_panel", 
  "args": {
    "panel": "output.exec"
   }
},
```

Comment: This command will hide *any* panel, not just the output panel. e.g. Find Panel, Console, etc. There is currently no other way to "toggle" the output panel on and off with Sublime Text 2 (I believe this is due to a bug with the output panel not having focus when it's initially shown).

Comment: Hmm, oddly enough, the console gets closed as well even though the `output.exec` panel was specified. Seems like a bug. Also, this command is currently unnecessary as `Esc` already closes all panels, including the output. Maybe in the future if they fix things, then this would be good (of course if they fix things, then hopefully they will add a toggle function instead).

Answer (score 1):

Building on akirk's answer you can make it toggle the build results panel by  copying some of the syntax used for the `escape` shortcuts.

Adding the following lines to the user key bindings will do part of the trick. As reported by some of the previous answers the `hide_panel` command will hide any panel, and pressing it a second time will reveal build_results.

```
{ 
    "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec"},"context":
    [
        { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ] 
},
{ 
    "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec"},"context":
    [
        { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ] 
},
```